# Construct a lambda term from a Böhm tree

Tags: trees, lambda-calculus

Given an acyclic graph, how can I build a lambda calculus term such that this graph is the term's [Böhm tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B6hm_tree)?

- If the Böhm tree is a finite tree (so the result is a strongly normalizing term).
- If the Böhm tree is an acyclic graph, but not necessarily a tree (so the result may not be normalizing).
- If the Böhm tree is not finite — is there a language of inifinite trees on which the process is decidable and which allows reaching every lambda term?